# CodeDeploy stuck on before install lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

I use ECS and am trying to do a to blue/green deployment, using CodeDeploy.

To trigger the hook I created a lambda function that contains just a return statement.

And I'm triggering the lambda function on before install hook.

But CodeDeploy progress seems stuck on before install.

I've checked lambda logs in CloudWatch, it finish perfectly.

Is there any solution here?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your lambda function here?

Comment: @Colwin Just same with first created lambda boiletplate.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/87ili1/help_aws_codedeploy_deployment_is_stuck_in/ in this thread someone had a similar issue maybe?

Comment: Can you add a return 0? to ensure that Code deploy thinks that the step succeeded?

Comment: @Colwin Doesn't work. (Both `return 0` and `return True`)

Comment: @Colwin To deploy blue/green, extra ec2 instance is needed. Maybe related about that? I will increase cluster instance count on `before install` and decrease cluster instance count on `after install`.